# Change true false in preferences in java

Tags: java, android

I'm attempting to use a Button from view class to turn off sound from app. (ie: mute)
When user pushes box i want code to check if value is already true or flase and then set to opposite using ID called 'mute'. I think i have the IF part setup, just need easy change SharedPreferences from true to flase and vice versa...

Here is code framework I'm testing(BEFORE):

```
SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
boolean cmute = getPrefs.getBoolean("mute", defValue);
if (cmute == true){                     

}
if (cmute == false){

}
```

I have tried various findings for the solution but most are too complex for this simple need I think..

Here is my rework AFTER posted suggestion:

```
if (cmute == false){


                    Editor editor = getPrefs.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("mute", true);
                    editor.commit();
                    Editor editor2 = getPrefs.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("notice", true);
                    editor.commit();



                }
                if (cmute == true){

                    Editor editor = getPrefs.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("mute", false);
                    editor.commit();
                    Editor editor2 = getPrefs.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("notice", false);
                    editor.commit();

                }
```

Comment: You should update your if statement to read: if(cmute){..} else {..}

Comment: @Droidster Jox means you can get rid of the `== true` part; also you don’t need a second `if`, just use an `else` clause.

Comment: @Droidster Jox was giving you an advise on your code style. `if (cmute == true)` is redundant. It's the same as `if (cmute)` because the if construct takes a boolean value anyway. Also mind the `else` construct.

Comment: -1 for still overcomplicating the logic here. Learn to use the not operator '!' as advised.

Comment: Also, no need to create two editors and call commit twice. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved with the [`Editor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html) interface:

> Interface used for modifying values in a SharedPreferences object. All
>   changes you make in an editor are batched, and not copied back to the
>   original SharedPreferences until you call commit() or apply()

That should work for you:

```
SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
boolean cmute = getPrefs.getBoolean("mute", defValue);
Editor editor = getPrefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("mute", !cmute);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Here is how it works GREAT, i tried ELSE but threw error.. thanks to everyone whom particpated. =]

Answer (score 0):

Comment on your AFTER suggestion version: There is no need to create an `editor2`, you don't even use it, you're referencing `editor` on subsequent lines. Also no need to call commit twice. And by using the not operator `!` as platzhirsch already suggested, you remove the need for `if(cmute...`

```
Editor editor = getPrefs.edit(); 
editor.putBoolean("mute", !cmute);
editor.putBoolean("notice", !cmute); 
editor.commit();
```